# swift : equivalent to respondToSelector

Tags: ios, swift

I have searched and used

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("userInterfaceIdiom"))
```

But couldn't worked for me. Show error as

> 'UIDevice' doesn't have member named 'instancesRespondToSelector`

Also tried this

```
UIDevice.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("userInterfaceIdiom"))
```

But got error as

> 'UIDevice' doesn't have member named 'userInterfaceIdiom'

But UIDevice belongs to NSObject which have member `instancesRespondToSelector`? Please point out my mistake or suggest correct way to do it?

Comment: if u found any answer is correct then accept or if u found correct one u just post swift is new to all of us ….

Comment: According to @Spynet comment, I posted new answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `instancesRespondToSelector` is still a class method and defintely not an instance method:

```
UIDevice.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("userInterfaceIdiom"))
```

**UPDATE#1**

because the `userInterfaceIdiom` is a property of the instance only:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().respondsToSelector(Selector("userInterfaceIdiom"))
```

Comment: +1 for your hints. Finally worked with `UIDevice.respondsToSelector(Selector("userInterfaceIdiom")`

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need this particular selector check. The recommendation of calling `[[UIDevice] currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]` only after a `respondsToSelector` check dates back to iOS 3.x. At that time, iPhones running iOS 3.1 didn't have the `userInterfaceIdiom` method — only iPads running iOS 3.2 did.

Not only is nobody trying to support iOS 3.x anymore, you can't deploy to it with Swift. All versions of iOS that you can target from Xcode 6 (whether you code in Swift or ObjC) support calling `userInterfaceIdiom`, and for that matter, so do all versions you can target from Xcode 5.

---

Second, there's no need to write `Selector("someSelectorName")`. The `Selector` type adopts the `StringLiteralConvertible` protocol, so anywhere you see an API that takes a `Selector`, you can pass a string literal.

So, you can write either:

```
UIDevice.instancesRespondToSelector("userInterfaceIdiom")
```

or

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().respondsToSelector("userInterfaceIdiom")
```

But you shouldn't...

---

Finally, it's generally a bad idea to use `userInterfaceIdiom` to make layout decisions — for one thing, it leads to the wrong layout decisions whenever you want to use the same view controller both as a portrait-full-screen view on iPhone and as the master view in a split view on iPad.

In iOS 8, the preferred way for a view controller to adapt to the frame it's presented in is to use traits. In your view controller code, write something like this:

```
if self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .Compact {
    // lay out for iPhone portrait or iPad master-split / popover
} else {
    // lay out for iPad detail-split / fullscreen
}
```

You can get more info about designing adaptive view controllers in [WWDC 2104 session 216: Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#216).

Comment: +1 for you. But minor suggestion about your answer. 1) You can say `userInterfaceIdiom` available upto ios 8 from ios 3.1, but we cann't sure with ios 9+, so this safe code with `respondsToSelector` will avoid crash, but won't work with deprecated versions 2) The above condition wouldn't relate to frame, just device(ipad or iphone).

Answer (score 1):

From @holex hint, I realize answer as

```
UIDevice.respondsToSelector(Selector("userInterfaceIdiom"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
UIDevice.userInterfaceIdiom?()
```

Comment: It would be next step as `UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom()`